# Parse objectAtIndex to Array and save NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm a little blocked  I have parse data I can download data Now I want to save this data with NSUserDefaults or whatever  because I need an Array  for someone reason I can see  only the first data but not all

```
[super viewDidLoad];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DataStaff"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    for (NSObject *comment in comments)
    {
        NSString *name = [comment valueForKey:@"name"];
         NSLog(@"%@",name);


        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:name];
        [defaults setValue:data forKey:@"key"];

                    NSArray *array =@[@"%@",name];
                 [_textField setSuggestions:array];
```

This information from my console

```
2015-08-26 12:31:35.547 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Internet IS OK
2015-08-26 12:31:38.654 RegisterED[17492:1760822] nsnsnsd
2015-08-26 12:31:38.664 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Honengar
2015-08-26 12:31:38.675 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Queytai
2015-08-26 12:31:38.682 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Endangurn
2015-08-26 12:31:38.686 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Endangurn
2015-08-26 12:31:38.688 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Chrilerwor
2015-08-26 12:31:38.691 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Anrayryn
2015-08-26 12:31:38.696 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Cryturage
2015-08-26 12:31:38.699 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Theipcha
2015-08-26 12:31:38.702 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Toimor
2015-08-26 12:31:38.705 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Restdan
2015-08-26 12:31:38.708 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Oldbser
2015-08-26 12:31:38.712 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Tonog
2015-08-26 12:31:38.717 RegisterED[17492:1760822] Saytinem


- (IBAction)read:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *defaultsFields = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *loadStrings = [defaultsFields stringArrayForKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"%@", loadStrings);


}


This information from my console
Saytinem
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save your array and next build your `NSUserDefaults` with your `NSMutableArray` :

```
// Initiliaze data
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Retrieve data
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DataStaff"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error)      {
    for (PFObject *comment in comments)
    {
        NSString *name = [comment valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",name);

        [data addObject:name];
    }

    // Save data
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"key"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}];
```

Comment: Jordan Montel you are big :)  your answer work  I voted in your favor but unfortunately it tells me I need reputation over 15 :( but I'll remember you whenI can vote